# 2024 Пожелания и Благодарность 

Tags: обсуждение, итоги-года

От всей души хочу поблагодарить ресурс **StackOverFlow** на русском за то, что он есть!!!

Желаю ресурсу хороших вопросов и большую активность.

Желаю каждому программисту найти свой цзен и улучшать подручные программы/приложения для человечества.

**2024** год — это восьмерка, тот год, когда мы перейдем в вечность, и многое изменится, как мы знаем на планете. Кто-то говорит, что 2024 год — это год возврата долгов, так вот я желаю, чтоб все Ваши старания от прочтения документации и решения багов вернулись к вам сполна в виде "флюидного" кода и бесперебойной программы. Не буду называть отдельных имен, но на этом сайте хочется и правда сказать каждому отдельное СПАСИБО!!! Я ценю Вас, и очень горжусь, что знакома с некоторыми даже лично. Тут всегда сплоченность несмотря ни на что, реактивность, чистота и порядок.

Терпения вам, чтоб обучать молодое поколение. Новых идей вам, чтоб творить новое и прочное. Сил и здоровья, чтоб всегда оставаться в форме. И просто хорошего и теплого настроения.

Пусть там где вы находитесь, будет хорошая погода всегда. Берегите себя, и пусть все ваши сокровенные желания исполнятся (если они несут добро) !!! ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Идеи подарков](https://tproger.ru/articles/podarki-na-novyj-god)

Все пожелания искренние и шли от души***

Если есть статистика за год, или свои слова пожеланий, предлагаю дополнить пост...

Comment: Спасибо! (надеюсь, переход в вечность будет увлекательным -))

Comment: И вам счастливого года. ヽ(^▽^)ノ
А статистику скоро опубликует сотрудник (каждый год так).

Comment: У меня такая статистика: я за этот год набрал 2 601 балл репутации из всех 2 734! И поднялся на 181 место!

Comment: С наступающим Новым Годом! Я рад что я с вами.

Comment: С Новым Годом!!!

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за поздравления, но можно всё-таки не переходить пока в вечность в наступающем году?  Или здесь уже всё исчислено, взвешено и найдено лёгким?

Comment: С новой годой, коллеги. Побольше сытных-жирных офферов на работу, побольше интересных вопросов и роста коммьюнити ruSO =)

Comment: Интересно, за что минус?

Comment: @Зонтик кто-то не хотел переходить в вечность ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @eccs0103 это вы где такой смайлик взяли? Из моего описания что-ли?

Comment: @чистов_n ( ͠° ͟ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @чистов_n Windows 11. Нажми `Win` + `V`, выбери какой смайлик захочешь

Comment: А на десятой винде это `Win` + `.`